# Как добавить префикс к заголовкам столбцов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как добавить префикс к заголовкам столбцов?

Нужно чтобы строка `0` стала столбцом `ta0`, `1` это `ta1`, и т.д.

[Файл с данными](http://file.sampo.ru/g4rvdw/) и их пример:

```
              0             1           2       3           4       5
0   -441.639313   -347.319153 -263.556610 -197.401276 -138.573822 -113.740761
1    120.495110    136.523438  114.086143  107.287186  119.825974  125.927505
2     65.145569     73.774193   52.752617   21.517670   -3.528697  -26.832869
3     41.820000     88.973755  121.634964  114.898605   97.940109   79.012726
4     19.254395     -7.459946  -44.183468  -82.682709  -92.896255  -80.979599
5     -2.394665    -31.808773  -34.409477  -46.254997  -50.180405  -35.535339
6    -12.968149    -18.853008  -20.897322  -30.898207  -45.858177  -52.879990
7    -20.086651    -10.154207    1.140410   13.075672   15.398544   14.408182
8    -23.867960    -36.757881  -36.384880  -30.956177  -32.172600  -25.396671
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто транспонируйте таблицу, воспользовавшись атрибутом [DataFrame.T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html).

Пример:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\temperature.csv", index_col=0)
res = df.T.add_prefix("ta")
```

---

результат:

```
In [169]: res
Out[169]:
          ta0         ta1        ta2         ta3        ta4  ...      ta35       ta36      ta37      ta38      ta39
0  -441.63930  120.495110  65.145570   41.820000  19.254395  ...  2.264282  -6.765351 -0.394719  4.364492 -3.910899
1  -347.31915  136.523440  73.774190   88.973755  -7.459946  ... -3.571153 -13.691976  5.948936 -2.725578 -6.496592
2  -263.55660  114.086140  52.752617  121.634964 -44.183468  ... -2.817787 -11.452227  0.344555 -9.603573 -3.693427
3  -197.40128  107.287186  21.517670  114.898605 -82.682710  ... -7.409706 -13.123294 -5.973748 -9.312523 -3.618781
4  -138.57382  119.825970  -3.528697   97.940110 -92.896255  ... -5.966316 -14.029428 -9.794986 -8.209969  2.084471
..        ...         ...        ...         ...        ...  ...       ...        ...       ...       ...       ...
20 -274.84744  -34.909725   8.542114   78.127990 -81.202170  ... -5.962484   2.168264 -9.493645  4.582136  0.215780
21 -291.17170  -25.038530   6.414797   71.361540 -81.361820  ... -6.351246   0.027203 -5.465869  4.581545  0.418393
22 -287.38160    4.946636  -6.291016   70.625850 -69.894140  ... -4.342758  -6.329304 -4.338036  5.411301 -3.715062
23 -305.19388   37.624283  -5.229207   61.476430 -59.063797  ... -4.650824  -9.340126 -2.030613  7.903496 -0.399862
24 -364.48984   56.975580  -2.559885   33.060562 -35.705856  ... -3.912640  -8.487836  1.641318  5.599786 -0.599182

[25 rows x 40 columns]
```